# How To Hide and Show DIV using CSS or Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

Basic Information:

Web Address: http://roverplusnine.xyz/product/RPN-9999-94-FD/
(This is a Wordpress site using 
N-Media WooCommerce Personalized Product Meta Manager Plugin"

Goal: Turn "Click Here To Choose A Logo" into a toggle button to show and hide image options. I have tried several different codes & javascript suggestions but I haven't been able to get it to work.

Any help that can be offered is appreciated.

I have the following HTML & CSS Mark-up:

```css
.showimagesdiv{
cursor: pointer;
background-color:#a3000c;
width: 175px;
text-align: center;
padding: 11px;
color: #fff;
}

#pre-uploaded-images-choose_logo label {
}

.pre_upload_image_box{
border: 1px solid;
background: #333;
text-align: center;
margin-top: 15px;
position: absolute;
z-index: 999;
right: 0;
display:none;
}

.pre_upload_image_box .pre_upload_image{
width: 100px;
overflow: hidden;
float: left;
text-align: center;
background-color: #FFF;
margin: 5px;
position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div data-dataname="choose_logo" id="pre-uploaded-images-choose_logo" style="width: 99%; margin-right: 1%;">
 <label for="choose_logo">
  <div class="showimagesdiv">Click Here To Choose A Logo
  </div>
 </label>
 <br>
 <div class="pre_upload_image_box">
  <div class="pre_upload_image">
   <img src="http://roverplusnine.xyz/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/2AndABrew-150x150.jpg">
    <div style="display:none" id="pre_uploaded_image_choose_logo-0">
    <img style="margin: 0 auto;display: block;" src="http://roverplusnine.xyz/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/2AndABrew.jpg"></div>
     <div class="input_image">
      <input data-price="" data-title="2 &amp; A Brew" data-type="image" name="choose_logo" value="{&quot;link&quot;:&quot;http:\/\/roverplusnine.xyz\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/07\/2AndABrew.jpg&quot;,&quot;id&quot;:&quot;5111&quot;,&quot;title&quot;:&quot;2 &amp; A Brew&quot;,&quot;price&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;url&quot;:&quot;&quot;}" type="radio"><a href="#TB_inline?width=600&amp;height=450&amp;inlineId=pre_uploaded_image_choose_logo-0" class="thickbox" title="2 &amp; A Brew">
      <img src="http://roverplusnine.xyz/wp-content/plugins/nm-woocommerce-personalized-product/images/zoom.png" width="15"></a>
      <div class="p_u_i_name">2 &amp; A Brew 
      </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: Why not just use jQuery's [`$.toggle()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_toggle.asp) method?

Comment: I ended up using the toggle method.... I was trying to do something with css, but this worked a lot easier. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you should use jquery for this.

And the javascript code will be like that

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       $('.showimagesdiv').on('click',function(){
           $('.pre_upload_image_box').toggle();
        });
});
```

Comment: @SHONWILLIAMS how to accept an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/tour  , https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 3):

```css
.showimagesdiv{
cursor: pointer;
background-color:#a3000c;
width: 175px;
text-align: center;
padding: 11px;
color: #fff;
}

#pre-uploaded-images-choose_logo label {
}

.pre_upload_image_box{
border: 1px solid;
background: #333;
text-align: center;
margin-top: 15px;
position: absolute;
z-index: 999;
right: 0;
display:none;
}

.pre_upload_image_box .pre_upload_image{
width: 100px;
overflow: hidden;
float: left;
text-align: center;
background-color: #FFF;
margin: 5px;
position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div data-dataname="choose_logo" id="pre-uploaded-images-choose_logo" style="width: 99%; margin-right: 1%;">
 <label for="choose_logo">
<script>var n=0;</script>
  <div class="showimagesdiv" onclick="n++;if(n==1){dd.style.display='block';}else{n=0;dd.style.display='none';}">Click Here To Choose A Logo
  </div>
 </label>
 <br>
 <div class="pre_upload_image_box" id="dd">
  <div class="pre_upload_image">
   <img src="http://roverplusnine.xyz/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/2AndABrew-150x150.jpg">
    <div style="display:none" id="pre_uploaded_image_choose_logo-0">
    <img style="margin: 0 auto;display: block;" src="http://roverplusnine.xyz/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/2AndABrew.jpg"></div>
     <div class="input_image">
      <input data-price="" data-title="2 &amp; A Brew" data-type="image" name="choose_logo" value="{&quot;link&quot;:&quot;http:\/\/roverplusnine.xyz\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/07\/2AndABrew.jpg&quot;,&quot;id&quot;:&quot;5111&quot;,&quot;title&quot;:&quot;2 &amp; A Brew&quot;,&quot;price&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;url&quot;:&quot;&quot;}" type="radio"><a href="#TB_inline?width=600&amp;height=450&amp;inlineId=pre_uploaded_image_choose_logo-0" class="thickbox" title="2 &amp; A Brew">
      <img src="http://roverplusnine.xyz/wp-content/plugins/nm-woocommerce-personalized-product/images/zoom.png" width="15"></a>
      <div class="p_u_i_name">2 &amp; A Brew 
      </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I ended up using the toggle method.